# Unable to plot a surface defined implicitly

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have the following function, which is a bit complicated:

```
   X1=Function[{r,\[Theta],l},4Re[(N[Integrate[E^(-(r^2+R^2)+2 I R l/r) (r+I R)^(2 l) 
(LaguerreL[1/2 (-l+n),l,(r^2+R^2)])^2 ,{R,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]])]];
```

where the function is constant in [Theta], this function defines a surface
(more or less cylindrical) through the equation X1(r, [Theta], l)=0.08, let's say.

Problem is that I'm unable to draw it neither with the commands:
ContourPlot3D, ListContourPlot3D of Mathematica, in matlab I was not able to deal with the Laguerre generalized polynomials to plot the isosurface :_(

Comment: This may help you with Laguerre: http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15916-generalized-laguerre-polynomial

Comment: What values does _n_ take?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *n* defines the order of your Laguerre polynomials and *r* is the length of a 3-dimensional vector *(x,y,z)* I get contour plots from your equation.

To make the calculations a little more efficient I defined your integral as a memo function:

```
fx1nl[n_, l_] := 
 fx1nl[n, l] = 
  4 Re[(N[Integrate[
       E^(-(r^2 + R^2) + 2 I R l/r) (r + I R)^(2 l) (LaguerreL[
           1/2 (-l + n), 
           l, (r^2 + R^2)])^2, {R, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]])]
```

(I don't know how to incorporate the dependence on *r* in that definition so have the following hack instead:

```
fx1[rp_, n_, l_] := fx1nl[n, l] /. r -> rp
```

Then you can go ahead with

ContourPlot3D[
 fx1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 1, 1] == 0.08, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 
  0, 1}]

... for instance.

I am not having much luck evaluating the function for other values of *n* and *l* so maybe you need to work those integrals out before going there.